# webpack-dev-server -hot mode stopped working

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

No matter what project I work on,
when I run: `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot`
my files arent being listen/watched and hot-reloading.

a demo project with minimal boilerplate I experimented on:
https://github.com/ueeieiie/webpack-hotreload-not-working

This is what I've tried:

- Opened old working projects, and its having the same problem
- Clearing npm's cache
- Uninstalling Node
- Switched IDE (I worked on vscode, and tried it also on Atom)
- Restart/ Shutdown computer

and nothing worked.

***any ideas?***

Answer (score 0):

**I found the source of the problem!**

one of my parent folders had a problemtic name.
It was called `(react-redux-weatherReport)`.

I guessed webpack didnt like the *round brackets*,could work properly.